# How do I remove 'being pressed' state from checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm overriding the `mousedown` event on a checkbox to enable selecting via dragging across other checkboxes. This involves having to do `event.preventDefault()` to disable the default text selection behavior.

Everything works as it should, except one annoying tic, namely the checkbox remains in the 'being pressed' state until I let go of the mouse (if that isn't clear, try holding down the mouse on a checkbox to see what I mean).

How do I revert the checkbox's state to either fully off or fully on (not 'being pressed')?

EDIT: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qFDmz/) with my code.

Comment: thanks, wasn't sure how best to paragraphinate my text

Comment: Does your mousedown listener return false?

Comment: no, i just do `.preventDefault()`. but I just tried, and making it return false as well doesn't change anything.

Comment: You could try manually firing a `mouseup` event in your `mousedown` override.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to find a cross-browser solution to your problem using the built-in form controls. Each browser handles them slightly differently. I would probably recommend doing some custom control replacement ala http://uniformjs.com/ or some similar plugin.

Comment: @Shmiddty: that's a bit overkill for this. i also have a lot of checkboxes and it takes too much processing power to re-style them all

Comment: @SimonWest: tried that, didn't seem to work unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is override some CSS for the "checkbox being pressed" state via the [:active pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3aactive).

```
​input[type=checkbox]:active {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    /* etc...*/
}​​​​​​
```

However this approach would only let you define your own rules for this state, not tell the browser to render a default system checkbox in its untouched state. This would of course be not bullet-proof but might come satisfactory in your case.

For maximum control over appearance you need to implement a custom checkbox component or use one of the many UI widget libraries out there (like Dojo, ExtJS, UniformJS etc.). These custom widgets basically hide the real `<input type="checkbox" />` giving you a "fake" element to interact with (but that mimics the native UI control functionality only it's fully themable).

Comment: ah i was wondering if there was a pseudo-class related to this. there's no way to change whether the pseudo class applies to an object? or to set the 'pseudo class' state via javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that's what I was talking about. You can only apply rules, not remove previous rules. But I wish there were a neat hack for this...

Comment: hmm and checkbox's don't have a `background-color` so it seems theres not much i can do... thanks though!